# Conditions for nonexpansive mappings to have fixed points

Tags: functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

This is exercise 4.30 of Foundations of Functional Analysis, Ponnusamy. This is the whole problem:

> Find a condition under which nonexpansive mappings have fixed points.

I have absolutely no idea where to start. Any help/insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your starting point is to look at the conditions for fixed-point theorems, and specifically the [Banach fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem).

You might also think about why the map

$f(x)=x+\frac 1 2 \text{ : }0\le x <\frac 1 2\\f(x)=x-\frac 1 2\text{ : }\frac 1 2 \le x <1$

From $[0,1)$ to itself does *not* have a fixed point.